# What to do when two shared libraries depend on the same version of a third-party compiled differently?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

My application depends on a certain version of xerces (compiled with specific flags):

```
$ ldd actimize_intelligence_server | grep xerces
    libxerces-c.so.28 => ./libxerces-c.so.28 (0x00002b3c1518f000)
```

A shared library (received from a client) also depends on xerces (apparently compiled with different flags):

```
$ ldd libgqt.so | grep xerces
    libxerces-c.so.28 => ./bin/libxerces-c.so.28 (0x00002b1f3d28f000)
```

Trying to start the application gives this error:

```
symbol lookup error: libgqt.so: undefined symbol: _ZN11xercesc_2_825DOMImplementationRegistry20getDOMImplementationEPKt
```

The missing symbol is this:

> xercesc_2_8::DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(unsigned short const*)

While the exported symbol from my libxerces-c.so.28 is this:

> xercesc_2_8::DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(wchar_t const*)

So I'm guessing that's the problem. Running strace when starting the application showed that my `libxerces-c.so.28` is being loaded:

```
open("/home/test/app/libxerces-c.so.28", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\365\31\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0555, st_size=5757256, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 6791128, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x2ba744950000
mprotect(0x2ba744e82000, 1044480, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x2ba744f81000, 299008, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x531000) = 0x2ba744f81000
close(3)
```

Without further occurrences of `libxerces-c.so.28`.

And here my little knowledge of Linux ends.

Can I somehow force the other `libxerces-c.so.28` to load even though it's already loaded?
If not, do I have any other options other than telling my client he needs to recompile his code to make it work with our xerces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that at all. Do not mess with binary compatibility like this- if you want to dynamically link to the same library, it must be compiled identically.

Comment: We ended up wrapping our xerces in a different namespace to avoid the collision.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what you need `libgqt.so` for, and how much your application depends on it.

*If* you don't really depend on `libgqt.so`, and just use a handful of symbols from it to do something for that particular client, then `dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, "libgqt.so", RTLD_NOW)` may be a viable solution. Documentation [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19082-01/819-2243/dlmopen-3c/index.html).

In general DeadMG is correct: your best bet is to make sure you use the exact same compilation of xerces, or you'll be hurt sooner or later.

Note that static linking xerces into your app is quite unlikely to be viable. Things will appear to work, only to crash at unpredictable times later.